# Finding strict prefixes in lucene

Tags: autocomplete, lucene

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature with Lucene. For example, if the user types "Lucene", the returned results may be "Lucene in Action" and "Lucene for Dummies".

The problem I'm having is that the field should start with with the searched text, it shouldn't be somewhere in the middle; searching for "Lucene" shouldn't return "Enterprise Lucene". Here's my code so far, which doesn't exclude the above:

```
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    addDocument(indexWriter, "Luceneinaction");
    addDocument(indexWriter, "LuceneforDummies");
    addDocument(indexWriter, "WhyisLucenesohard");
    addDocument(indexWriter, "Managing Gigabytes");
    addDocument(indexWriter, "The Art of Computer Science");
    indexWriter.close();

    Query query = new PrefixQuery(new Term("title", "lucene"));

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 10);
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : docs.scoreDocs) {
        System.out.println(searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc).get("title"));
    }
```

Is there an easy way to solve this? It appears that PrefixQuery is not compatible with StringField, and I can't find a tokenizer that doesn't split on whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

When you index a text field in solr, it will be tokenized. For example, a whitespace tokenizer splits documents upon each space in the scentence. So you might not be able to search based on string positions.

For your use case, you should copy/store this field as a string type(with keyword toeknizer) instead of text. Then you will find solr stores the full scentence as a single string, allowing you to perform regex pattern searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a field for Fulltext-Search you should always use Textfield, because this will be analyzed (base on your given analyzer).
See javadoc of: [Field](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html)

It's really important that you understand what kind of field you need to use for which purpose.

For your use case, if you search in a TextField you don't have to use a PrefixQuery.